# Suggestions for creative use of post format feature, or themes that use them well

Tags: theme-development, css

I'm looking for themes or examples of sites that use the post format feature in an interesting way.

I suppose adding special styling for each post format would be a good start.  But if anyone knows of it being used in a cool or creative ways by a premium or free theme feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post on WordCast: 
[WordPress Post Format Eye-Candy: Tumblr Style Theme Inspiration Showcase](http://wordcastnet.com/2011/wordpress-post-format-eye-candy-tumblr-style-theme-inspiration-showcase/)

Also Digging into WordPress uses them and just wrote a post about it:
[Tumblr Links with Post Formats](http://digwp.com/2011/04/tumblr-links-post-formats/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+DiggingIntoWordpress+%28Digging+Into+WordPress%29)

Comment: @laura The DigWp Article, idea of linking the title to the resource is possibly a good idea for some use cases.  Thanks for the Eye Candy post as well, good start to brain storm novel ways to use the other post formats, 'chat', 'gallery', 'image', 'link'.'quote', 'status', 'video', 'audio'

Comment: Sure! It's hard to come across solid examples - seems like most developers haven't started with them yet.

Answer (score 2):

[Theme Foundry Shelf](http://thethemefoundry.com/shelf/) comes to mind, it got some press out of being one of the first paid themes added to WordPress.com

Comment: As a side scroller horizontal layout, it think it is a creative use of the post format feature. Was just wondering if there were other interesting use scenarios for vertical style layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Well.... I use post-formats on my personal site, http://www.rvoodoo.com

More interesting though, may be the code. 
http://www.rvoodoo.com/projects/wordpress/wordpress-tip-post-formats-get-template-part-loop-php-and-maximum-child-theme-compatibility/

THere were so many options, and opinions when the formats came out.  If you are interested, there's a link to my approach.

Comment: I like the extensibility of this approach for child themes.  I generally already use get_template_part() coupled with WordPress inherent template logic, instead of using conditional tags in one loop file.  Your method as described in your post pretty much extends this down another level.

Comment: Yup, that was my logic. I was trying to maintain get_template_part usage as much as possible to make the theme as child theme extensible as possible. using loop-template.php or format-format.php in a child theme allows for a load of customization options

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a theme (to be used on my blog when it's ready) with post formats. You can see a cropped screenshot, detailing several of the post formats here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xraga.png

When I get it far enough along, I'll be releasing it to the public.

Also, [WordPreh](http://wordpreh.com) uses custom post formats, though you don't see much variation in most cases. The most obvious thing is that 'link' post titles link directly to the destination, rather than to the permalink of the post.

Comment: Oh, and note that on the 'link' example, the little world icon will change to the favicon for the site being linked to.

Comment: I'll look out for you release.  That world icon is a nice subtle touch.  I've been playing with the idea of implementing a filter, possibly using some jquery to show and hide post formats on a home page...

Comment: I like linking the title of a 'Link' format to the original source. I do that on my blog, and on VoodooPress. Seems almost natural...except for it's kind of not normal default WP behaviour... which is why your icon is an excellent touch